# Spring MVC form date (jquery) mapping field

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am trying to map a date retrieved from DB in my jsp using Spring MVC and some jquery.
I have this in my jsp:

```
<form:input path="startDate" id="startDate" type="text" cssClass="input date"/>
```

In my spring controller I have this code:

```
model.addAttribute(TVA_FORM, TvaMapping.modelToForm(tvaService.findCurrentTva()));
```

The `modelToForm` method code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
TvaForm tvaForm = new TvaForm(tva.getId(), tva.getRate());
tvaForm.setStartDate(sdf.format(tva.getStartDate()));
```

The form:

```
public class TvaForm {
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private Float rate;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String startDate;

    // Contructors/ getters / setters
}
```

And the entity:

```
public class Tva {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "RATE", nullable = false)
    private Float rate;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('input.date').datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ]).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
```

What am I doing wrong? why `startDate` is not getting mapped into my jsp field?

Thank you for yoyr help guys!

Answer (score 0):

On your jsp page, make sure the value of modelAttribute of the `<form:form>` tag is the string value of TVA_FORM you put in model,

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="string value of TVA_FORM" action="your action url" methodParam="submit">
```

Here is How I map a date type and at the same time take the advantage of jquery's datepicker.

In my command class, my date is still the java.util.Date type. There is no need to convert it to String. I use Spring's @DateTimeFormat to handle the transforming from Date to String and back forth.

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = ArmsConstants.DATE_FORMAT_SHORTDATE)
@NotNull
private Date effectiveDate; 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = ArmsConstants.DATE_FORMAT_SHORTDATE)
```

In my jsp page,

```
<th><form:label for="ori.effectiveDate" path="ori.effectiveDate" cssErrorClass="error">Effective Date *:</form:label></th>
<td><form:input path="ori.effectiveDate" class="datepicker" type="mdate" cssErrorClass="errorInput datepicker"/>
```

And the jquery is just as simple as

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Oh, And I am also using the jquery maskedinput plugin to format the picked date on the jsp page, of course the format should be the same as what I used in the @DateTimeFormat

```
$("[type='mdate']").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
```

Comment: Hi Haiqi, I have this in my jsp `<form:form modelAttribute="tvaForm" id="tvaForm" commandName="tvaForm" cssClass="node" action="tva/save">`

Comment: And in my controller: `private static final String TVA_FORM = "tvaForm";`

Comment: Without the whole picture, it is hard for me to tell what went wrong. The only thing I can suggest about the code given is that "commandName" is not needed in <form:form/>, and "id" is not needed in <form:input/> if it is the same value as "path". Are the other values mapped to the modelAttribute in your tvaForm?  To single out the problem, you might want to comment out the jquery part and try again.

Comment: it works when I comment the jquery code, but I need it to let the user pick a date, so I just don't know why it's not working when I'm using jquery!